# We want to mirror Image file structure from existing site to Magento

Tags: product-images

We are rebuilding our site from an HTML site front end with shopping cart back end to a full Magento store.  We currently come up high in Google's image results for a variety of our product photos and want to keep a similar folder structure in Magento if possible.
Currently we have this type of file structure, with each image category defined: (I am using turtle and dolphin jewelry as an example):

```
/images/turtle-jewelry/jade-turtle-earrings.jpg
/images/dolphin-jewelry/silver-dolphin-necklace.jpg
```

This is the file path which Magento is assigning by default:

```
/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/650x/040ec09b1e35df139433887a97daa66f/a/r/jade-turtle-earrings.jpg"
```

Is there any way to do this? I would really like to keep images organized as well. Or, would we be better off using `.htaccess` redirects for our images until Google finds them?
Thank you for any help or advice!

Comment: How many images?